# How to add a map to a list in Dart

Tags: arrays, flutter, object, dart, arraylist

Given this map object,

```
var _map = {
  'category': 'Africa', 
  'products': [
    {
      'countryName': 'Namibia', 
      'population': 1800000, 
      'capital': 'Windhoek', 
    }, 
    {
      'countryName': 'Kenya', 
      'population': 20000000, 
      'capital': 'Nairobi', 
    }, 
  ]};
```

I would want to add this map below to the value 'products',

```
var _newMap = {
  'countryName': 'Rwanda', 
  'population': 3000000, 
  'capital': 'Kigali', 
},
```

And get a result like this,

```
{
  'category': 'Africa', 
  'products': [
    {
      'countryName': 'Namibia', 
      'population': 1800000, 
      'capital': 'Windhoek', 
    }, 
    {
      'countryName': 'Kenya', 
      'population': 20000000, 
      'capital': 'Nairobi', 
    },
    {
      'countryName': 'Rwanda', 
      'population': 3000000, 
      'capital': 'Kigali', 
    },  
  ]}
```

How do I achieve this in Dart. What would you suggest I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty :

```
  final productsList = _map['products'] as List<Map<String,dynamic>>;
  productsList.add(_newMap);
  _map['products'] = productsList;
```

Comment: Glad I could help, would you mind marking this as accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution.

change **_map** type from '**var**' to '**Map<String, dynamic>**'

```
Map<String, dynamic> _map = {
...
}
```

```
_map['products'].add(_newMap);
```